# Prove that the chromatic index of a $k$-regular graph with a cut vertex is greater than $k$

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

We are given a graph in which there exists a cut vertex, v, in which G-v creates two components. Also the degrees of all the vertices in G are equal and equal to k, making it k-regular. We're then asked to prove that χ'(G) > k.

I know for one vertex, we'd need k different colors for all the edges coming towards it, and I think that since all those edges don't go directly to one vertex we can have more than k colors in general. Also if the graph is k regular and has a cut vertex couldn't that vertex be any vertex in the graph? In any case I'm not too sure how the information about the cut vertex would relate to the proof, which is kind of where I am stuck right now.

Comment: Fun unrelated sidenote: It is necessary that your graph $G$ is finite. If $G$ were infinite, you could take the infinite "line" graph which is just a line of vertices, each connected to their (two) neighbors. Then $\chi(G) = 2$, and any vertex is a cut vertex which creates two components, and $G$ is $2$-regular. :)

Comment: **Hint.** You know that, if $G$ is $k$-regular and $\chi'(G)=k$, then $G$ has an even number of vertices? Then, for any vertex $v$, some component $H$ of $G-v$ must have an odd number of vertices. (We are assuming of course that $G$ is finite!) If $H$ is a **proper** subgraph of $G-v$, then at least one of the $k$ colors, call it "red", does not occur among the edges joining $v$ to $H$.

Comment: @aras Yes, $\chi(G)=2$, and also $\chi'(G)=2$ which is more to the point. :-)

Comment: So then since χ'(G) != k, then we don't have a two regular graph. But then I am not sure for what k-regular graph we could remove a vertex and have two different components. The degrees are all the same so I'd assume that the graph is k-connected.

Comment: So there are some graphs, like a 3-regular graph, which can have cut vertices, so we'd end up having an odd number of edges coming from each vertex, and so then from an edge from the cut vertex we can find that there's a cycle on that side that goes back to the cut vertex through another edge that has to have more edges than the degree of the vertices, since otherwise the vertices on that side would have k-1 degree. So then we could use k colors for those edges but we'd end up having at least two edges with the same color incident on each other. I'm still a little unsure though.

Answer (score 4):

Let $G$ be a (finite) $k$-regular graph with a cut vertex $v$, and assume for a contradiction that $G$ admits a proper edge coloring with $k$ colors. Fix such a coloring; each vertex of $G$ is incident with one edge of each color. Without loss of generality, we assume that $G$ is connected.

Since $v$ is a cut vertex, $G-v$ has at least two connected components, $G_1$ and $G_2$; and $v$ is adjacent to a vertex $u_1$ in $G_1$ and a vertex $u_2$ in $G_2$. Without loss of generality we assume that the edge $u_1v$ is colored red and the edge $u_2v$ is colored blue.

Let $H$ be the spanning subgraph of $G_1$ consisting of the edges in $G_1$ which are colored red or blue. In $H$ the vertex $u_1$ has degree $1$ and all other vertices have degree $2$. But this is impossible in a finite graph.